# When should I instantiated my classes in Web Services (ASMX)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx, lifecycle

I have the follow WebServise (asmx):

```
public class MyService : WebService
{
    private readonly UserHandler _UserHandler;
    private readonly RoleHandler _RoleHandler;

    public MyService()
    {
        _UserHandler = HandlerFactory.CreateUserHandler();
        _RoleHandler = HandlerFactory.CreateRoleHandler();
    }
}
```

The MyService() constructor will be executed for each request, so is It the correct place to instantiated _UserHandler and _RoleHandler? 
Should I replace my current code with the follow implementation?

```
public class MyService : WebService
{
    private static readonly UserHandler _UserHandler = HandlerFactory.CreateUserHandler();
    private static readonly RoleHandler _RoleHandler = HandlerFactory.CreateRoleHandler();
}
```

With the last implementation _UserHandler and _RoleHandler will be instantiated just one time and all request will be use that instances.

Who Is the best implementation?

Thanks.-

Answer (score 0):

I prefer on constructor.

From the point of view of language are the same, both are instantiated on constructor.
The constructor's form (for me) is better because in the future if you want you can change the constructor and *inject* mocked `RoleHandler` and `UserHandler`

Comment: Thanks. What about the performance and used resources (garbage collector)? If I use the constructor solution It will be instantiated the `RoleHandler` and `UserHandler` for each request.

Comment: Yes the constructor instantiate for each request, while the other is static and is instantiated once when app start.

Comment: So, What is the best solution?

Comment: For me the constructor. WebService is instantiated per each request, so static on no-static is the same. On constructor you have the opportunity to add a new constructor and inject mocked RoleHandler and UserHandler for unit test.

Comment: I known that WebService is instantiated per each request but static properties is instantiated just one time.